# Angular 5 material button give invalid array length error once clicked to send an id and generate a token

Tags: php, angular-material, jwt, angular5, cryptojs

I am trying to use JWT with angular 5 and PHP to generate a token. For testing reasons, I encrypted the `userid` variable using `CryptoAESJs` library and send it via `post` method to php script:

```
getToken()
{
    let userid = 123;
    let key = "coded";
    let encUserID = crypto.AES.encrypt(userid, key);
    const headerOptions = new HttpHeaders().set
        ('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    const params = new HttpParams().set('userID', encUserID);

    this.http.post('http://aff.local/jwtTest.php', params, {
      headers: headerOptions,
      responseType: 'json'
    }).subscribe(
      res=>{
        console.log(res);
      },
      error=>{
        console.log(error);
      }
    )
}
```

I send it to the PHP script:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application\JSON');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once "CryptoJSAES.php";
require_once('JWT.php');

ini_set('log_errors', 0);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$key = "coded";
$id = $_POST['userID'];
$token = CryptoJSAES::decrypt($id,$key);

$jwt = JWT::encode($token, $key);


$jwtDecode = JWT::decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256'));

echo json_encode($jwtDecode);
?>
```

Inside my `app.component.html`, I added a button:

```
<button mat-raised-button  (click)='getToken()'>Click Me</button>
```

So run the `getToken()` method when click event is fired.

Once clicked, I got the following error at the console:

> ERROR RangeError: Invalid array length
>
> at WordArray.init.clamp (core.js:272)
>
> at WordArray.init.concat (core.js:237)
>
> at Object.pad (cipher-core.js:415)
>
> at Object._doFinalize (cipher-core.js:492)
>
> at Object.finalize (cipher-core.js:163)
>
> at Object.encrypt (cipher-core.js:675)
>
> at Object.encrypt (cipher-core.js:833)
>
> at Object.encrypt (cipher-core.js:201)
>
> at AppComponent.push../src/app/app.component.ts.AppComponent.getToken
>   (app.component.ts:20)
>
> at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (AppComponent.html:1)

Is it a problem with material ? Or with the browser ? Or it is a problem with the value sent from Angular to PHP ?

**EDIT**

```
//Imports
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import * as crypto from 'crypto-js';
```

Comment: Is CryptoAESJs library imported to your app.component.js? It seems the error is related to this library

Comment: Yes. I will update my script.